# 3 pages viewed as spread, but still print individual pages

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design

I am working on a three page spread in InDesign that will be viewed online as a PDF. I can make the spread appear correctly when the PDF is opened (all three pages next to each other), but how do I set it up so that if someone wants to print it, each page will print on its own sheet? So far I can only get them to print all together on one page, or I have to really mess with the print settings each time which is obviously less than ideal for customers.

Thanks in advance!

ALM

Answer (score 1):

Export 2 PDFs, one for print in single pages, one for the web as spreads.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this.
It is only possible to display two separate pages next to each other, not more.
The only possible way — but you are already doing this — is to export as a sheet, and then you have the mess with printing.
You could change to two pages or like Lucian said provide two different PDFs.
Another way would be a PDF with 4 Pages, the first one is a sheet with all Pages next to each other and 3 single pages for printing.

But none of these solutions is ideal.